# Increment pointer bit by bit

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I know that pointers increment by the number of bytes that sizeof(type_i_am_using) returns. However, is there anyway to make a pointer increment bit by bit?

Comment: Did you mean byte by byte?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want an address somewhere in the middle of your data type, you can get it, but thinking of it as a pointer to an item of your data type is somewhat incoherent. If you want to point to a *bit* rather than a *byte*, that's not possible.

Comment: There is no bit-level resolution in memory address space.

Comment: you can create a user-defined-type that acts like a pointer and can be incremented bit by bit (though what kind of semantics you want is unclear ATM). but my guess is that you don't know what you're doing and trying to be overly smart - and consequently achieving the opposite effect. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ?

Comment: That's like mowing your lawn grass by grass, but makes less sense ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, is there anyway to make a pointer increment bit by bit?

If you meant "byte by byte": No, because there is something called alignment. Addresses that are not aligned cannot be addresses of valid objects, hence a pointer containing an unaligned address is invalid. Most operations with invalid pointers invoke undefined behavior. If you want to e.g. access array subobjects of a standard-layout class where that array is the first member, cast the pointer to the element type of the array and work from there. There is no direct point in what you describe.

If you meant literally "bit by bit": There are well-known methods of iterating through all bits in an object representation using a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Most computer architectures don't let you address individual bits. If you need to, say, iterate through a sequence of bits, you need to iterate over the bytes instead (using a `char *`, or a pointer to a larger, unsigned integral type) and extract bits through bit shifting and bit mask operations. `(value >> x) & 1` will extract the bit at index `x` from the right; `value |= 1 << x` will set it to 1, and `value &= ~(1 << x)` will set it to 0.

Note that `vector<bool>` is specialized to pack its values into individual bits.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer can't be incremented bit by bit because a char is the smallest amount of addressable memory. This is mandated in the language specification. If you need to start looking inside individual bits then you most likely will want to use the bit shifting/masking operations.

For example to look inside a character you might want to do something like this:

```
bool get_bit_n(unsigned int n, char x){
    return (1 << n) & x
}
```

Also you might want to look into [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Answer (score 0):

No. Character is the smallest thing that machine can address. You can however traverse all bits in machine using bit operations. In C++ you can use `std::bitset` or `std::vector<bool>` specialization, or bit fields.